# ionic 3: refresh current page on network change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using the `cordova-plugin-network-information` plugin to detect changes in network connectivity within my Ionic 3 app.

Currently, I've created a component called `network-status` that injects the `ToastController` and displays a Toast message when the status changes. Here's the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { ToastController, Toast } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'network-status',
  templateUrl: 'network-status.html'
})
export class NetworkStatusComponent {
  status: string;

  constructor(private _toastCtrl: ToastController, private _network: Network) {

    let noInternetToast: Toast;
    let onlineToast: Toast;

    this._network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {

      noInternetToast = this._toastCtrl.create({
        message: 'No Internet Connection ',
        position: 'top',
        cssClass: 'failure'
      });

      noInternetToast.present();
    });

    this._network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {

      // TODO: figure out way to reload current view

      onlineToast = this._toastCtrl.create({
        message: 'Back online ',
        position: 'top',
        duration: 2000,
        cssClass: 'success'
      });

      noInternetToast.dismiss();
      onlineToast.present();
    });
  }
}
```

When the connection comes back online, I'd like to refresh whatever view the user is currently on. At the moment, the `<network-status>` component is embedded in `app.html`.

Running Ionic 3.6.0 and Angular 4.3.6.

Thanks!

Comment: Create one method which is called from constructor and if not internet is connected dont call that method and when internet connected event fire call same method which is called from constructor.